# ElasticSearch high level client search failed occasional

Tags: elasticsearch

when I using ElasticSearch High Level Client by submit asyncSearch,I got wrong response occasional. That shard total > 0 but successful and failed is 0, and I can't find any log about this search. for example, searchBuilder log as follow:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {...},
  "aggregations": {
    "term0": {
      "filter": {
        "match_all": {
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "countCOUNT_DISTINCTdid": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "did",
            "precision_threshold": 40000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then get wrong response content:

```
{
  "took": 1002,
  "timed_out": false,
  "terminated_early": false,
  "num_reduce_phases": 0,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 20,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

But when query on Kibana as above, the correct result is:

```
{
  "took" : 231,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 20,
    "successful" : 20,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "term0" : {
      "doc_count" : 8526098,
      "countCOUNT_DISTINCTdid" : {
        "value" : 3929368
      }
    }
  }
}
```

by the way, other search request at the same time using the same client is ok.

Why does this happen and how to avoid it? Thanks a lot for any hints